Show that $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{6b}{a}-\frac{6a}{b}+ 23}$ is a perfect square natural number.
the problem
Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero real numbers such that $a^2-b^2=3ab$. Show that $\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{6b}{a}-\frac{6a}{b}+ 23}$ is a perfect square natural number.
my idea
So we have to show that $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{6b}{a}-\frac{6a}{b}+ 23$ has the form $k^4$
Then I started processing the form of this number: $\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{6b}{a}-\frac{6a}{b}+ 23=\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{2(a^2-b^2)}{a^2}-\frac{2(a^2-b^2)}{b^2}+ 23= \frac{2a^2-b^2}{a^2}+\frac{2b^2-a^2}{b^2}+23=\frac{a^2+3ab}{a^2}+\frac{b^2+3ab}{b^2}+23=25+\frac{3b}{a}+\frac{3a}{b}=25+\frac{3(b^2+a^2)}{ab}$
I guess I just got stuck here. I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me!

With $a=b$ , we will get $\sqrt{25}$

@Prem $a=b$ don't satisfy $a^2-b^2=3ab$.

Your $b^2+3ab$ should be $b^2-3ab$

Ohhh right , @jjagmath , thank you !

Note that the relation $a^2 - b^2 = 3ab$ implies that
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b} - \frac{b}{a} = 3.  \quad (*)
\end{align}
On squaring the above equation, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{a^2}{b^2} + \frac{b^2}{a^2} = 11. \quad (**)
\end{align*}
On plugging the relations from $(*)$ and $(**)$, we obtain,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{6b}{a}-\frac{6a}{b}+ 23} = \sqrt{11 - 18 + 23} = \sqrt{16} = 4,
\end{align*}
which is a perfect square.

Set $c=\frac{a}{b}$. The given condition on $a$ and $b$ becomes $c^2=3c+1$.
The expression to investigate is $$c^2+\frac{1}{c^2}+\frac{6}{c}-6c+23$$ which you can simplify using $c^2 = 3c+1$ to reduce any power of $c$.
